# Malformed Policy Document: Has prohibited field Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an IAM Role and IAM Policy using Terraform.

I'm getting this error:

```
│ Error: error creating IAM Role (asg-domain-join-policy): MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
 
  status code: 400, request id: 53fa1ae0-f22f-4f2e-8aa6-1947421eae9b

  with aws_iam_role.ad_join_role,
  on iam.tf line 30, in resource "aws_iam_role" "ad_join_role":
  30: resource "aws_iam_role" "ad_join_role" {
```

My current code for the IAM Role is the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ad_join_role" {
  name                 = "asg-domain-join-policy"
  assume_role_policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.asg_domain_join_policy.json
  permissions_boundary = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:policy/****"
}
```

The code for IAM Policy is the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "asg_domain_join_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
      "ssm:GetDocument",
      "ssm:ListAssociations",
      "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
      "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation",
      "ssm:CreateAssociation",
    ]
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["ec2"]
    }
}
```

I'm unsure why I'm getting that error.

Comment: The resource argument is for the `assume_role_policy`, and the document in the value provided is for an attached policy. You may want to read this documentation for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `assume_role_policy` can have a document which specifies only the `AssumeRole` action. What you have to do is split your policy to create separate ones for being able to assume a role, and being able to attach other permissions to the role.

For example:

```
# Allow EC2 instances to assume the role
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "asg_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }

  }
}

# Create the policy which allows other actions for the EC2 instance
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "asg_domain_join_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
      "ssm:GetDocument",
      "ssm:ListAssociations",
      "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
      "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation",
      "ssm:CreateAssociation"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ad_join_role" {
  name               = "asg-domain-join-policy"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.asg_assume_role_policy.json
 
  # Attach the policy
  inline_policy {
    policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.asg_domain_join_policy.json
  }
}
```

Some things to note in this example:

- The second policy is attached as an [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html). This is fine, if the policy is shorter, otherwise you may want to use [`aws_iam_policy_attachment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy_attachment)
- The resource type for the actions in the second policy is a wildcard `["*"]`. If you want more granularity for your actions on the policy, you may want to check out [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awssystemsmanager.html) to see which action allows what kind of resource type. Obviously, `["ec2"]` is not a valid resource type.

Answer (score 1):

Your resource block is using an incorrect reference. ec2 is not a resource. If you are referencing an instance you need to use aws_instance.my_ec2_instance, or if you want to allow all resources you can put "*".

Comment: I've just tried this and I'm still getting the same error, unfortunately. I'm basically trying to create this policy on step 1: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-configure-your-ec2-instances-to-automatically-join-a-microsoft-active-directory-domain/